# Exclude specific resource for a pod iOS

Tags: ios, macos, cocoapods

I'm creating a pod which have a XIB file, that pod should work for OSX and iOS but when I run:

`pod lib lint`

I get this error:

```
/Users/folder/Pod/Assets/MyXib.xib
/* com.apple.ibtool.errors */
/Users/folder/Pod/Assets/MyXib: error: iOS xibs do not support target device type "mac".
```

how could I exclude that file for the mac target?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [CocoaPods reference](https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html#group_multi_platform_support), you could use the multi-platform support:

> For example one might want to store resources which are specific to only iOS projects.

```
 spec.resources = "Resources/**/*.png"
 spec.ios.resources = "Resources_ios/**/*.png"
```

Comment: yes it works, but your answer need an updated. Seems that cocoapods don't recognize the work "spec", it needs to be changed to "s". After that, the line could be changed to "
s.resource_bundles = {
    'MyPodBundle' => ['Pod/Assets/**/*.*']
  }
"

can you update your answer with that?

Comment: @Gabox the first line is something like `Pod::Spec.new do |spec|`. If you use `s` there, you should be using `s` in the following lines.

Comment: @Gabox can you explain a little about what `resource_bundles` and `MyPodBundle` are?

Comment: yes, it is the name of the bundle and resource_bundles is the way to create more than one bundle

Comment: @Gabox: Thanks for explaining. Anyway I'm just providing a way to distinguish between platforms. You could put whatever you want after `spec.<platform>`. :)